Why is the drive time and walk time service area analysis (network analyst) returning polygons of descending sizes?
I am trying to build a very basic network analysis layer to show the service area for transit. All I need to show is the service area that takes 10 minutes to walk (or 1/3 mile) from transit stops/“facilities.”I’m not doing any restrictions and don’t have elevation fields. For some reason it is calculating smaller areas for polygons and listing them in descending order (shown in the contents pane). I have watched 6 YouTube tutorials and still can’t figure out what is going wrong.
A possible clue is that it takes only seconds to calculate the service area. There was one time where I did something that produced a service area and it took 6-7 minutes, which seems more accurate. The service area still was wrong though and I have no idea how I got it.
(https://imgur.com/a/PhUHOJU)

To incorporate screenshots please use the [edit] button beneath your question to access its Picture button.
